# How do you tell python to get the first 6 numbers from a text file and put them horizontally

Tags: python

I need some help extracting 6 numbers from a text file and then extracting the next 6 numbers but separating them in groups. In total, I should have 8 groups of 6 numbers.

```
def oly():
    my_file=open("/Users/Mariano/Google Drive/Radio Show/Junior & Plundhy Show/shoedata.txt","r")
    line=my_file.readline()
    for line in range(0,0):
        print (line,)
    while line:
        print (line,)
        line=my_file.readline()
```

Comment: how many number per line?

Comment: You should specify what you need help with exactly. You supplied code; what's wrong with it?

Comment: Also how are the numbers organized? 1 number per line? 6 numbers per line?

Comment: Sample input and expected output could help.

Comment: Ignore the "for line in range(0,0)" range loop, what I need help is extracting the first 6 numbers from a text file with 48 random numbers and separating them into 8 groups in successive order. 6 numbers per line in the python module.

Comment: @OliverCracker 6 numbers per line? So essentially it's already organized?

Comment: @OliverCracker since it's only 48 random numbers, can you post sample contents of a file?

Comment: Yeah. I just need to separate every 6 numbers in one line.  
This is the ouput: (but i need every 6 numbers in one line horizaontally not vertically .
6

7

3

9

6

6

5

5

5

5

5

5

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

4

7

8

9

10

2

6

10

2

4

5

10

8

10

8

7

6

5

4

3

2

7

5

5

4

5

4

5

4

Comment: @OliverCracker What's the delimiter? A space or a comma between numbers?

Comment: I don't know what a delimiter is. I updated the program, I just don't know how to get every 6 numbers separated in 8 lines. 


def oly():
        my_file=open("/Users/Mariano/Google Drive/Radio Show/Junior & Plundhy Show/shoedata.txt","r")
        line=my_file.readline()
        while line:
            print (line,)
            line=my_file.readline()

Comment: I don't know what a delimiter is. I updated the program, I just don't know how to get every 6 numbers separated in 8 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `str.split` on whitespace and then split into `n` size chunks:

```
with open("/Users/Mariano/Google Drive/Radio Show/Junior & Plundhy Show/shoedata.txt") as f: # with closes you files
    nums = f.read().split() # split line into individual elements
    # get 6 element slices from nums 
    for chk in (nums[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(nums), 6)):
        print(chk)

['6', '7', '3', '9', '6', '6']
['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
['8', '4', '7', '8', '9', '10']
['2', '6', '10', '2', '4', '5']
['10', '8', '10', '8', '7', '6']
['5', '4', '3', '2', '7', '5']
['5', '4', '5', '4', '5', '4']
```

If you need actual `ints` then `map` each row to int:

```
for chk in (nums[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(nums), 6)):
        print(list(map(int, chk)))

[6, 7, 3, 9, 6, 6]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 6, 10, 2, 4, 5]
[10, 8, 10, 8, 7, 6]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 5]
[5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4]
```

If using `python2` use  `xrange`  and you don't need to call list on `map`.